# Properties of Legendre/Cramer's transformation of the moment generating function

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions, large-deviation-theory

Let $X \in L^1$ be a random variable on some probability space, define $M(\theta) \equiv E(e^{\theta X})$ as its moment generating function and let $D(M) \equiv \{\theta \in \mathbb{R} : M(\theta) < \infty\}$.  I'm reading a really toxic set of lecture notes which has the following lemma as an exercise and I cant find the same theorem online.  I'm having trouble proving bullet point (iii) in particular:

[image]

---

**My attempt at a proof follows.  You may ignore bullet point (i) and (ii) if you wish, but they may be helpful:**

For ease in notation I define $f_a(\theta) \equiv a\theta - \log(M(\theta))$

**Bullet point (i):** Note $f_a(0) = 0 \leq \sup_\theta f_a(\theta) = I(a)$, convexity follows easily since $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $$(\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b)\theta - \log (M(\theta)) = \lambda (a \theta - \log(M(\theta))) + (1-\lambda)(b\theta - \log (M(\theta))) \leq \lambda I(a) + (1-\lambda)I(b)$$ and we can take the supremum of the LHS over $\theta$.

We also have, by the convexity of $-\log(x)$ and Jensen's inequality, $$-\theta \mu = E(-\log(e^{\theta X})) \ge -\log(E(e^{\theta X})) = -\log (M(\theta))$$  Rearranging gives $f_\mu(\theta) \leq 0$ for all $\theta$ (trivially for $\theta$ such that the mgf is infinite) so that the supremum $I(\mu) \leq 0$.  Lastly, we see that for each $b \leq a \leq \mu$, we have the existence of a $\lambda \in [0,1]$ so that $a = \lambda b + (1-\lambda)\mu$.  From convexity, non-negativity and the fact that $I(\mu) = 0$, it is immediate that $I(a) \leq \lambda I(b) \leq I(b)$.  The identical set of ideas works for $\mu \leq a \leq b$

**Bullet point (ii):**  For $a \ge \mu$, and any $\theta < 0$, we have trivially $f_a(\theta) \leq f_\mu(\theta) \leq 0$ from bullet point (i).  The conclusion is trivial from here, and a similar set of inequalities is true for the other case.

**Bullet point (iii):**  This is where I am lost.  I know that $M'(\theta)$ exists $\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$ since $X \in L^1$ (for those who are unaware of how to prove this, simply find an appropriate dominating function for the difference quotient and apply dominated convergence), and moreover $M'(\theta) = E(Xe^{\theta X})$.  So for the last part of (iii), we can note that $f_a(\theta)$ is **concave** in $\theta$ and differentiable so that any critical point is a global maximum.  Thus, it suffices to find $\theta$ so that (just take the derivative and set to 0) $$a - \frac{M'(\theta)}{M(\theta)} = 0$$

This would actually solve the whole question, as it will show that we have a convex function that is finite at every point in $\mathbb{R}$ (and thus finite on any open interval $(a,b)$) and is thus continuous (see here for example for a proof of this fact: [Proof of "every convex function is continuous"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/proof-of-every-convex-function-is-continuous)).  I just need help with the existence of such a $\theta$.  Please help if you can!

(As a sidenote, the fact that this is an exercise in a set of lecture notes is genuinely utterly cruel)

Comment: for a different look at the convexity of the cumulant, you may enjoy  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600908/convexity-of-log-of-moment-generating-function

Comment: Are these lecture notes available online? If yes, would you mind giving a link to the lecture notes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proof that for any given $a$, if we define

$$g(\theta) = \frac{\mathbb{E_\mu}[X e^{\theta X}] }{ \mathbb{E_\mu} [e^{\theta X} ] }$$

there exists $\theta^*$ s.t. $g(\theta^*) = a$.

First, here is the intuition: You are given that X ~ $\mu$ and $\mu$ has full support on $\mathbb{R}$. You can consider $a$ as the expectation of $X$ under the measure $\mu_\theta$ where :

$$ d \mu_\theta = \frac{e^{\theta x}}{\mathbb{E_\mu}[e^{\theta X}] } d \mu $$

First, note that this measure is well defined for all $\theta$ since your MGF is finite for all $\theta$. As $\theta$ grows, this measure puts more and more mass on larger values, so eventually, under this measure, the expectation will arbitrarily grow. (Provided that $\mu$ puts mass on these large values, which is how we will use that full support condition) We can play the same game with negative $\theta$s, and we will show that you can get $g(\theta)$ to be arbitrarily large and small. Since $g(\theta)$ is continuous, intermediate value theorem will give you the result.

Now, let's do it rigorously:

Let $M$ be large. We know that $\mu(X \geq M) = \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ since $X$ has full support on $\mathbb{R}$.

We also have that $$\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E_\mu}[X e^{\theta (X-M)} 1_{X < M} ] = 0$$ by dominated convergence theorem, so there exists a $\theta_1$ s.t.  $|\mathbb{E_\mu}[X e^{\theta_1 (X-M)} 1_{X < M} ]| < \epsilon$

We also have by a similar argument a $\theta_2$ s.t. $|\mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta_2 (X-M)} 1_{X < M} ]| < \epsilon$

In what follows, let $\theta = \max(\theta_1, \theta_2)$

$$ \frac{\mathbb{E_\mu}[X e^{\theta X}] }{ \mathbb{E_\mu} [e^{\theta X} ] } = \frac{\mathbb{E_\mu}[X e^{\theta X} 1_{X \geq M} ]  }{ \mathbb{E_\mu} [e^{\theta X} ] } + \frac{\mathbb{E_\mu}[X e^{\theta X} 1_{X < M} ]}{ \mathbb{E_\mu} [e^{\theta X} ] }$$

For the first term, we have that $\frac{\mathbb{E_\mu}[X e^{\theta X} 1_{X \geq M} ]  }{ \mathbb{E_\mu} [e^{\theta X} ] } \geq \frac{ M \mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta X} 1_{X \geq M} ]  }{ \mathbb{E_\mu} [e^{\theta X} ] } = \frac{ M \mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta X} 1_{X \geq M} ]  }{ \mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta X} 1_{X \geq M} ] + \mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta X} 1_{X < M} ] }$

Now, let's divide top and bottom by $\mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta X} 1_{X \geq M} ]$. Note that we can do this because $\mu$ has full support. We get

$$\frac{M}{1 + \frac{\mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta X} 1_{X < M} ]}{\mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta X} 1_{X \geq M} ]}}  =  \frac{M}{1 + \frac{\mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta (X - M) } 1_{X < M} ]}{\mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta (X - M)} 1_{X \geq M} ]}} > \frac{M}{2}$$.

where for the last inequality we note that $\mathbb{E_\mu}[ e^{\theta (X - M)} 1_{X \geq M} ] \geq \epsilon$ since $e^{\theta (X - M)} \geq 1$ when $X \geq M$.

The second term is thankfully easier; we divide top and bottom by $e^{\theta M}$

$$\frac{\mathbb{E_\mu}[X e^{\theta (X - M)} 1_{X < M} ]}{ \mathbb{E_\mu} [e^{\theta (X-M)} ] } \geq -1$$

where again we invoke the fact $\mathbb{E_\mu} [e^{\theta (X-M)} ] > \epsilon$.

Now, we are done, since we showed that for an arbitrary $M$, there exists a $\theta$ s.t. $g(\theta) > M/2 - 1$. We can play the same game with $-M$ which gives us another $\theta'$ s.t. $g(\theta) < -M/2 + 1$, which completes the proof by continuity of $g$ and intermediate value theorem.

Comment: That's two of my questions you're answering today; really awesome!  I should really be able to think on these things and get them myself at this point - I have no idea how I'm going to ever do my own research

Comment: I will put this chat link here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111003/sharing-grad-student-struggle-with-another-grad-student so that you can ping me for particularly important questions (TBH I don't really know how chat works on stackexchange).; let me know if this does not work.

Comment: I'm so sorry I never replied to this - I completely forgot.  The link unfortunately doesn't work at the moment (I'm not sure if it did but now doesn't since it's been too long).  Either way, thanks again for your help on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to use **strict convexity**, **shift properties** and **quadratic approximations** of **cumulant generating function**, all of independent interest.

Define it as $\psi_X(\theta)\triangleq \log \mathbf{E}\mathrm{e}^{\theta X}$, Hoelder's Inequality implies
: $$ \mathbf{E}\mathrm{e}^{p_1\theta_1 X_1+p_2\theta_2X_2}\leqslant  \left(\mathbf{E}\mathrm{e}^{\theta_1 X}\right)^{p_1} \cdot \left(\mathbf{E}\mathrm{e}^{\theta_2 X}\right)^{p_2}
$$
for positive $p_1,p_2$ such that $p_1+p_2=1$ and any $\theta_1\not=\theta_2$, thus by taking the logarithm we obtain that $\psi(\cdot)$ is convex. The equality happens when $\mathrm{e}^{\theta_1X}\propto \mathrm{e}^{\theta_2X}$, equivalently when $X$ is constant a.e.

As for the quadratic approximation, take $x_0$ such  $\mathbf{P}\{X>x_0\}>0$ (e.g. median). By $\mathrm{e}^{t}\geqslant 1+t+\frac{\max(t,0)^2}{2}$ we get
$$
\psi(\theta) = \theta x_0 + \log\mathbf{E}\mathrm{e}^{\theta(X-x_0)} \geqslant \theta x_0 + \theta\mathbf{E} (X-x_0) + \frac{v\theta^2}{2} = \theta\mathbf{E}X+\frac{v\theta^2}{2},
$$
for some constant $v$ (we can take $v =\mathbf{E}(X-x_0)^2\mathbb{I}\{X>x_0\}>0$).

Now, assuming $X$ is not constant, we deal with the function
$$
f_a(\theta) = \theta a - \psi_X(\theta) = -\psi_{X-a}(\theta),
$$
which is *strictly concave* (by the first fact) and *falls to negative infinity* at both infinities (majorized by $O(t)-\frac{t^2v}{2}$ due to the second fact). So it has a unique global maximum.

Since we know that the first derivative exists, the global unique maximizer $\theta$ satisfies
$$
0=\frac{\partial f_a(\theta)}{\partial \theta} = a-\frac{\partial \psi_X(\theta)}{\partial \theta},
$$
as claimed.